# How would I find a list of the best answers on SO?

Tags: discussion, site-usage

I'd consider it very useful and informative to be able to browse the list of the highest voted ANSWERS on SO.

Not only would it shed great insight into what the general populous finds useful, it would allow one to learn from example how a great answer should be written.

[Yes, I know I could just click "Users"->"Jon Skeet"]

Comment: Damn. It's mostly jokes, quotes and stories. We're as bad as mathematicians... ;)

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://data.stackexchange.com

```
select top 100 Id, Score from posts where PostTypeId = 2 order by score desc
```

Comment: Outstanding! Great answer! Many thanks!! :D

Comment: You are welcome.  I wish there were a way to filter out the CW answers.

Comment: It might be more useful with a list of links: `select top 100 Title, 'http://stackoverflow.com/a/'+CAST(Id as VARCHAR), Score from posts where PostTypeId = 2 order by score desc`

Answer (score 3):

You could browse the answers that have received the [Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) badge.  That link takes you to the users who have won it.  Each user's best answers are at the top of their list.

Comment: Each user's name on that page is a link to their profile.  Scroll down past their questions to see the list of their answers.  Anything that's won the Great Answer badge will be at the top of the list.

Comment: This answer also applies to "How to find all fun answers" question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the monthly [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) might help you in this.

Comment: http://www.statoverflow.com/sandbox/

Comment: Cheers for the extra link

Comment: Jonathan Sampson: It seems that the sandbox is only useful if you know what you are looking for or have some idea of the schema. It would be helpful if you included that information.

Comment: I belive this is it? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox